# Differentiating home root paths for domain and subdomain

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

I have a web structure with a domain and a subdomain, let's call it `example.com` and `blog.example.com`.
I want to be able to track both the main domain and it's subdirectory within the same Analytics profile so I've entered the same tracking code across `example.com` and `blog.example.com`

**Tracking Codes:**

This is the tracking code for the domain:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-xxxxxxxx-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
 var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
 ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
 var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>
```

And here is the code for the subdomain:

```
 var _gaq = _gaq || [];
 _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-xxxxxxxx-1']);
 _gaq.push(['_setDomainName','example.com'],['_trackPageview']);

 (function () {
 var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
 ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
 var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
 })();
```

**Issue**

Notice I've used `_gaq.push(['_setDomainName','example.com'],['_trackPageview']);` for subdomain tracking.
I see the post pages from the blog in the Analytics reports, but I can't distinguish between the homepage of the site and the homepage of the blog, they both appear in the reports in the same way (a slash /)

**Question**

Can anyone give me some insight on how to differentiate the homepage of the domain from the homepage of the subdirectory in GA reports?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To see the domain name along with the request path in the reports, create an advanced filter for your profile with the following settings:

- Filter Type: Custom filter > Advanced
- Field A: Hostname
- Extract A: (.*)
- Field B: Request URI
- Extract B: (.*)
- Output To: Request URI
- Constructor: $A1$B1

[image]

You can also create a profile for each subdomain. For example for `site1.com`:

1. New profile named `site1.com`
2. In the new profile create a filter `Include site1.com traffic only`
3. Filter type set as *Custom filter* and *Include*
4. Filter field as *Hostname*
5. Filter pattern as `^site1\.com$`

Repeat for each domain. Data will only be collected once the profile is created.

([Google's explanation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/resources/concepts/gaConceptsAccounts#profiles))